# Always show branch have diverged in Git command line, how can I get rid of it?

Tags: git, command-line

> 

```
∞myname@CAN-L-NB20005 ~/bxxx (feature/BB-2xxxx ✗ ) % git st
On branch feature/BB-2xxxx
Your branch and 'bxxx/hotfix/1.37' have diverged,
and have 220 and 20 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

My branch BB-2xxxx came from main branch bxxx/hotfix/1.37 at first, but I have already rename my branch and I rebase my branch to another main branch Develop, now my branch and main branch work properly, but why my branch show diverged all the time?

I tried to reset hard command, but it didn't work.

Comment: are there other authors committing to the branch?

Comment: And how did you rebase? If you rebased it should mention that branch in the status message.

Comment: You rebased your *local* tracking branch, but it is still tracking the remote branch that *wasn't* rebased. You shouldn't have rebased the tracking branch in the first place.

Comment: You probably should have *merged* the hot fix into your feature branch.

Comment: @ti7 No one, I work on it only.

Comment: @chepner I have pushed my branch to the remote, but doesn't work as well.

Comment: Rebasing your local branch rewrites the branch history. That means a normal push will fail; you'll have to `--force` the push. Make sure you are satisfied with your local changes before force-pushing.

Comment: I tried to delete all the local branches and reset hard to the remote branch, it didn't work as well. But check out the commit number, then create another branch with the same name, and I finally get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to delete all the local branches and reset hard to the remote branch, it didn't work as well. But check out the commit number, then create another branch with the same name, and I finally get rid of it.